# Azure AD for IdP and SP

Tags: azure, saml-2.0

Looking to deploy Single Sign-on authentication on an on-premises application (SAML integrated) with Azure AD. In real world, we have two servers a. Identity provider & b. Service provider for SSO.

However, in this case, can i use - Azure AD for IdP and also as SP (same server) for on-premise application SSO authentication? Would be great if someone please explain how would be the flow of authentication in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD can be an IDP only.

It cannot function as an SP to another IDP.

Could you please elaborate on "also as SP (same server) for on-premise application SSO authentication". What do you mean here? What's the use case?

You can add custom SAML applications to AAD as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-custom-apps).

Comment: I am looking to use federation server which could be Okta, Azure or ADFS for on-premises application for SAML integration. Now, i have just one server federation server internally, so can i use that for SP and IdP request?

Comment: Okta and Azure AD are cloud only. If ADFS is the internal server, yes it can be an SP to Okta or Azure AD and an IDP for internal applications.